# Как открыть exe файл консольного приложения VS Code при компиляции?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы при компиляции консольного приложения сразу открылся exe файл (как это происходит в Visual Studio). Язык C#. Зачем мне это? Очень не нравится работать через терминал. Требуется разворачивать его на треть экрана, что создает проблемы для работы с кодом. Уменьшать шрифт кода или увеличивать/уменьшать размер терминала каждый раз тоже не слишком удобно. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Файл `launch.json` -> `"console": "externalTerminal"` если не ошибаюсь. А вообще, хотите "красоты" и удобства, используйте полноценную студию, а не блокнот на стеройдах.

Comment: Visual Studio 2022